# Issue with data table in Angular js when using $apply for invoke watcher

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-datatables

[image]I am working on angular data table and getting issue related to $scope variable data not updating on UI after assign from second API, for this I used the $apply to invoke watcher and the UI is updated proper but the angular data table started behave wired, when I click the column for sorting the table get blank and sometimes showing the old assigned data of first api on UI.

Below screen shot include the method which I am calling on api success response and changing the $scope.records value.

Can any one help how can I resolve this or should I move on ng-table.

Comment: Are there code examples you can share?

Comment: @ChristiaanMolendijk Thanks,
Above I added the method screenshot which I am calling on api success response.

Comment: @Dom Can you please help ?